# Random table view cell height is not working perfectly

Tags: swift, uitableview, nstablecellview

I am designing a chat app in which I am using the UITableViewAutomaticDimension property of table view when I am setting the label lines to 6 then all cells height is according to the text which label contains but when I increase the number of lines for label then some cells have extra height. Even when scrolling it then cell height again changed.You can check the image so that you can understand it easily thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to give label constraints from top and bottom, rather than center vertically.
2. Give vertical content hugging priority

Comment: I do the same but no luck

Comment: can you share the constraints that you have given for that particular cell?

Comment: top 8,bottom 8 and leading 8,trailing equal or greater 100 all from superview

Comment: are you somehow calculating or caching height manually for the cells?

Comment: No i don’t calculate hei

Comment: try doing invalidateIntrinsicContentSize on the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: worked thanks this is the exact solution invalidateIntrinsicContentSize  on cell